# How to get the return value of an on demand executed function?

Tags: javascript

I have a script file MyScript.js in the folder TEMPLATES\LAYOUTS\MyProject\Scripts which looks like this:

```js
var MyCompany = window.MyComapny || {};
MyComany.MyProject = MyComany.MyProject || {};

MyCompany.MyProject.alertingFunc = function (firstName, lastName) {
  "use strict";

  var bondStyle = 'My name is ' + lastName + ', ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '.';
  alert(bondStyle);
};

MyCompany.MyProject.returningFunc = function (firstName, lastName) {
  "use strict";

  var bondStyle = 'My name is ' + lastName + ', ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '.';
  return bondStyle;
};

SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs('MyScript.js');
```

I can manually load this script on demand and call `alertingFunc` this way:

```js
SP.SOD.registerSod('MyScript.js', '/_layouts/MyProject/Scripts/MyScript.js');
SP.SOD.execute('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.alertingFunc', 'Big', 'Boss');
```

Now to the question: **How can I on demand execute a function which returns a value?**

The `SP.SOD.execute` function does not provide a return value. There is a callback version.

```js
SP.SOD.registerSod('MyScript.js', '/_layouts/MyProject/Scripts/MyScript.js');
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.returningFunc', function (result) {
  alert(result);
});
```

The callback function does not get the return value of `MyCompany.MyProject.returningFunc` as parameter injected.

One possible solution is to use `LoadSodByKey` this way

```js
SP.SOD.registerSod('MyScript.js', '/_layouts/MyProject/Scripts/MyScript.js');
LoadSodByKey(NormalizeSodKey('MyScript.js'), function () {
  var result = MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss');
});
```

`LoadSodByKey` is nowhere documented in MSDN. It is a private function which can be changed in future releases. Therefore I would like to use the public documented APIs.

**EDIT: Solution**

I have found a solution which is a combination of the `LoadSodByKey` and `SP.SOD.exececuteFunc` aproach above.

```js
SP.SOD.registerSod('MyScript.js', '/_layouts/MyProject/Scripts/MyScript.js');
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.returningFunc', function () {
  var result = MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss');
});
```

In the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) the description of the parameters is wrong.

> ### **Parameters**
>
> *key*
>
> Type: String
>
> The name of the file containing the function that is executed.
>
> *functionName*
>
> Type: String
>
> The name of the function that is executed.
>
> *fn*
>
> Type: Function
>
> The function that is called once functionName has finished executing.

In my tests the function *functionName* is never called. Only the callback function *fn* is executed whenever `SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, functionName, fn)` is executed.

You have to be careful when passing the value of the *functionName* parameter. It must be a valid function or object. These are all valid calls:

```js
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.returningFunc', function () {
  var result = MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss');
});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject', function () {
  var result = MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss');
});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany', function () {
  var result = MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss');
});
```

If *functionName* does not exists in MyScript.js then the callback function *fn* is only executed once.

```js
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.nonexistentFunc', function () {
  alert(MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss'));
});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject.nonexistentFunc', function () {
  alert(MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss'));
});
```

The text "My name is Boss, Big Boss." is alerted only once. In contrast to the above these statements

```js
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject', function () {
  alert(MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss'));
});
SP.SOD.executeFunc('MyScript.js', 'MyCompany.MyProject', function () {
  alert(MyComany.MyProject.returningFunc('Big', 'Boss'));
});
```

show the message box twice.