# How to get the return value from SP.SOD.executeFunc?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, client-object-model, jquery, csom

I have the same scenario as what this below question has:

[How to get the return value of an on demand executed function?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79341/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-an-on-demand-executed-function)

I have `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getPageTitle);` function which gets me the title of a page.
I want to be able to get the return of this method to a variable 
something like:

`var par = SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getPageTitle);`

I have tried this but doesnt work

Asking this question as there is no response on the above question. Please take this as a priority thing because the old question was asked 2 years back.
Kindly help in this regards.

Please note: I am using it in Sharepoint Online but its a generic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
     var par = getPageTitle();
     //Do the rest of your logic here
});
```

The third parameter is a callback function. The `SP.SOD.executeFunc` call doesn't actually return the value of your callback function. So you can supply your own callback function as above and do whatever you like (including calling other functions and processing their return values).

[SP.SOD.executeFunc Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: No, This doesn't work, It gives par as undefined.

Comment: I was assuming `getPageTitle()` is your function. If you are just looking to get the current title of the page then you can just use `document.title` and forget all this `SOD` stuff.

Comment: No its a function which returns something. Its an example which I posted.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion about when par will be populated. If you put lines of code immediately following the `executeFunc` call then par would not have been populated yet. Your logic needs to happen in the callback function (I've moved the `var par` declaration here to help emphasize that).

Comment: yes it might happen here, as there is an asynchronous call which is happening which populates the return value. Its in `executeQueryAsync` method. Any idea how i could get the return to work if its coming from an asynchronous call?

Comment: Also, based on your previous question I think you are misunderstanding the second parameter. The second parameter ensures that that "function" (think object) has been created. So you would specify `SP.ClientContext` there because you need not just the `SP` object to be ready but also the `ClientContext` object since you will want to use it in your callback function.

Comment: It is never going to return there. The other option is to delay all of your code with an `SP.SOD.executeFunc` call. Then you are free to assume `SP.ClientContext` is available. At this point we are getting beyond this question and you'd probably get more help posting generic JS questions on StackOverflow related to asynchronous calls and callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your answer seems relevant to the question that i asked hence I marked yours as the Best answer. With below answer as well as your comments i now know that i was not going the right direction. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The `SP.SOD.executeFunc` function will always return undefined, as most SharePoint JS functions that run asynchronous code do. The third argument, your `getPageTitle` callback function, can be declared to return something, but that something cannot be captured by the `SP.SOD.executeFunc` function to be able to do `var par = SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getPageTitle);`.

From your comments on Chris Kent's answer, I understand your `getPageTitle` function is doing some **asynchronous logic** as well (hint: `executeQueryAsync`). In this case, you need another callback function because you cannot return the result of the `executeQueryAsync` function in your `getPageTitle` function.

Here is how your code could look like if you were to get the web title (instead of page title):

```
var web;

// Run this when the async call to get the web title succeeds.
function getWebTitleSuccess() {
    var par =  web.get_title();

    console.log(par);
    // more logic here that depends on your web title value.
}

// Run this when the async call to get the web title fails.
function getWebTitleFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log(sender);
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function getWebTitle() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();        

    // Note the "web" variable has been declared globally so it can be accessed 
    // in other functions (e.g. the "getPageTitleSuccess" function).
    web = context.get_web();

    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(getWebTitleSuccess, getWebTitleFailure);
}

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getWebTitle);
```

I hope this clarifies why you cannot return a value, but rather use callback functions to get what you need.

When you work with asynchronous JS, you need to use callback functions that will run only after the async execution completes. Using the `return` keyword works only in **synchronous** scenarios because it immediately returns a value without waiting for the async logic to complete.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the elaborate explanation on this and your response. I will try your answer.